# What happens if you set your integration package to Unicode?

Tags: unicode, ssis, integration

I'm importing data from flat-files (text files). I do not know which encoding they will use, it may be unicode, or it may be ASCII. What happens if I just choose "Unicode string [DT_WSTR]" (Or unicode data) in my integration package. Would it be able to read ASCII without issues? I am using SSIS 2012.

Comment: you should use according to your destination datatypes because i will throw a conflict that error between unicode and non unicade data....

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if I just choose "Unicode string [DT_WSTR]" (Or unicode data) in my integration package. Would it be able to read ASCII without issues?

The encoding that Microsoft misleadingly call “Unicode” is actually UTF-16LE, an encoding based around two-byte code units.

UTF-16LE is not compatible with ASCII (or any of the locale-specific ANSI code pages) so if you read a file this is actually encoded in an ASCII superset you will get unreadable nonsense.

There's no magic ‘do the right thing’ option for reading characters from files, you *have* to know what encoding was used to create them. If you can see an encoded Byte Order Mark on the front of the data that usually allows you to make a good guess, but otherwise you're on your own.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there a step/tool that can read the "Byte Order Mark" ? I have never heard of that, and I'll be researching but if there is a step/tool in SSIS that could recognize that, that'd be great.